# Django RestFramework - parent-child model serializer with DB views?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a serializer that returns a parent record with its children embedded in the response json object.

My model for the parent and child are both based on database views:

```
class ProductContributorView(models.Model):  # its a model of a view
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   product_id = models.ForeignKey('ProductTitleView', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='contributors')
   sequenceNumber = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
   role = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=1408)

   class Meta:
      managed = False  
      ordering = ['sequenceNumber',]


class ProductTitleView(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   isbn = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   titleText = models.CharField(max_length=300)

   class Meta:
      managed = False  
      ordering = ['titleText', 'isbn',]
```

Here are the serializers:

```
class ProductContributorViewSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductContributorView
        fields = ('id', 'product_id', 'sequenceNumber', 'name', 'role', 'description')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        contributor = ProductContributorView.objects.create(
            id=validated_data['id'],
            product_id=validated_data['product_id'],
            sequenceNumber=validated_data['sequenceNumber'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
            role=validated_data['role'],
            description=validated_data['description'])
        return contributor


class ProductTitleViewSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    contributors = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductTitleView
        fields = ('id', 'isbn', 'titleText', 'contributors')
```

Here are the views:

```
class ProductTitleViewList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProductTitleView.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductTitleViewSerializer

class ProductContributorViewList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProductContributorView.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductContributorViewSerializer
```

The basic idea is to have the contributors - author, illustrator, etc - returned with the book title based on the FK in the ProductContributorView view matching the id in the ProductTitleView.

When I run this, however, I get the following error:

```
1054, "Unknown column 'jester_productcontributorview.product_id_id' in 'field list'"
```

I didn't specify product_id_id in the field list, and I've also tried referring to the field as just product in the field list, but it still repeats the _id_id suffix.  Hoping someone will point me to documentation where the FK naming conventions are explained or tell me what to change in the field list.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the database views are written separately and note generated by makemigrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just want to try renaming that `product_id` ForeignKey to just `product`.

This hints to why it may be broken, I suspect it's breaking somewhere in the serializers inspection of your models regarding the naming of the `product_id` field on the model.

When you define a `ForeignKey` on a model there are two properties available for that field.  One is the property you define, the `ForeignKey` object, and you should use this to get the related *model*. Behind the scenes Django also creates another property which appends `_id` to the the foreign key's name, this property represents the IntegerField  on the database which stores the relation. If you were to view the table in psql you will see the `_id` columns (and in your case, `_id_id`).

Comment: Thanks A.J. that fixed the error message - so my DB view (since this is an 'unmanaged' model) still has the field as product_id, but in model.py I've now changed it to product = models.ForeignKey(...) so now I get back results for the ProductContributorsView.  Still have work to do to get the child records to show up in the ProductTitlesView -- right now is just a list with the product_id integer, but you've answered the initial question, so THANK YOU.